# Migrate the discussion list in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I want to migrate a Discussion List from one site collection to another site collection with all content. Is there any way to do it? We can not save the list as a template. Because we want to keep all the original information, like the Created By.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Walkdek's answer :-

Simplest way is when you create a template you have the option of including the existing content (Save List As Template > Include Content). When you move the tmplate to hte other site sollection and create a new list based on it then your data will be there.

You can also do this using SharePoint Designer - select the list, select Copy then find destination and select Paste.

Another option is [Gary Lapointe's STSADM extensions such as gl-exportlist and gl-importlist](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists.html)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at the SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard (http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard) by Chris O'Brien. The tool uses the built-in migration API and it should allow you to move your content.